# Force canvas redraw from recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to create a custom progress bar. But I'm using a recursive function that updates data for it, I can't update canvas that is in my progress bar.

Here are parts of my code:

```
var length = 0;

recursiveFunction = function(){
   length++;
   updateLength(length);
   //some work
   recursiveFunction();
}

updateLength = function(length){
   setLength(length);
}

setLength(length){
    var c = document.getElementById(canvas);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fc0";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, length, 10);
}
```

All these functions are in different JS files and in different classes.

Problem is that canvas doesn't redraw in `setLength` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with JavaScript being single-threaded and can only do one thing at the time. As long as that code is running everything else such as updating to screen has to wait.

To get around it you can introduce some asynchronicity to your code pausing the code enough to allow the screen to be updated.

For example (note: this change alone will probably not work without performing other changes):

```
recursiveFunction = function(){
   length++;
   updateLength(length);
   //some work
   requestAnimationFrame(recursiveFunction);  // makes call async
}
```

The function will now end but an event is added for future use (usually 16.7ms in this case). In the mean time the canvas can be updated to screen.

But not without problems of course. Context is changing and since it's a recursive function you may want to pass in arguments. Although not shown in the post which ones if any, you could instead of `requestAnimationFrame()` use `setTimeout()` which allow you to pass in arguments. You can also use `bind()` if you're depending on context (i.e. `this`).

```
// example of bind
requestAnimationFrame(recursiveFunction.bind(this));
```

The [`setTimeout()` can take more arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) than delay:

```
setTimeout(recursiveFunction.bind(this), 17, arg1, arg2, arg3, ...);
```

An alternative to this is to use ***[Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)***. This will allow you to run your code as fast as possible at a separate thread, and once in a while send back a message to main host containing progress so far which will allow canvas to be updated independently. This is the recommended path if the function is long-running. Web workers has [good support](http://caniuse.com/#search=web%20workers) but won't work with older IE or Opera Mini.

Comment: `requsetAnimationFrame` did not help me first. I've used `closures` and `setTimeout` to relieve the thread. Maybe now `requsetAnimationFrame` can help me, but it works without it so...